# JNI error has occurred. Please check your installation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng

I'm trying to run a very simple test using TestNG, but I'm getting this error message.  I tried reading the previous answers, but it is not working to me. I would be happy if someone could help me out, since I'm just a beginner in TestNG. This is the error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: did you resolve this issue. please share how ??

Comment: @kaustubh93 check out my answer. It solved my problem with this error.

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is an [issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/140) with `testNG` running on eclipse. As of this post you can try a workaround to fix your error by adding the [jcommander jar file](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/1.7) in your build path and then run your `testNG` suite from eclipse.

If you want to run using command prompt or terminal, here's how to do it on MAC -

```
java -cp "PATH/TO/TESTNG.jar:PATH/TO/jcommander-1.7.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Similarly replace your path for windows too and your test suite will run as without any errors using command prompt.

Comment: That colon should be a semicolon: `PATH/TO/TESTNG.jar;PATH/TO/jcommander-1.7.jar`

Answer (score 4):

This typically happens when your JDK version and JRE version are not compatible or when the required JRE version is not installed.

To  correct the error use **Window -> preferences ->
compiler -> compiler compliance level** and change the JRE version to existing JRE version.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/140.

Add jcommdar.jar to classpath and then run: 
java -cp "C:\TestNG\testng.jar;C:\TestNG\jcommander.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Answer (score 2):

To overcome from this problem, we need to download the jcommander1.7 jar file.
to download the jar file visit below url and get jcommander1.7 jar file

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcommander17jar.htm

Process to implement jcommander1.7 jar file-

Right click on the project->Properties->click on the liabraries->click on the Add external jars->navigate to the location where jcommander1.7 jar file is downloaded.

and run your script, now your script will run successfully.

Comment: This problem can be resolve if we use Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Add `jcommdar.jar` to `classpath` and then run:

```
java -cp "C:\TestNG\testng.jar;C:\TestNG\jcommander.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

It is really helped for me.

Comment: Could you please explain that how to do that? Where in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error while running my testng.xml. I replaced my selenium server jar which was included(build path) by a local user from his local path. Copy the jar files to the project folder(lib) and include them in your project. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the similar kind of error when was trying to run DemoTest.xml file as `TestNG Suite` using Eclipse IDE.

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/TestNGException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testng.TestNGException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

For me the issue got resolved when added testng-6.11.jar in the build path of the project. Follow the below mentioned steps:

Right click on the `project` -> `Build path` -> `Configure build path` -> `Libraries tab` -> `Add external jars` -> Choose testng-6.11.jar and `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

- Any of your files are present at the compile time but it's not reachable
  at the execution time
- You need to crosscheck both compile-time and run-time environment &
  class paths

Answer (score 0):

For Linux:

Try to change the configured version of Java using the following command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This command will show:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3
```

Choose the appropriate version and done.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this JNI error in my Windows machine while tried running an Java program using TestNG. Though I had kept Eclipse updated along with the latest TestNG jar and plugin installation.
Thereafter I got to know about jCommander.jar file, added this jar to my project build path (as external JARs) and error was fixed.
The latest JCommander.jar can be downloaded from here -
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error and below are the things I tried to fix-

1. Added jcommander jar file - Not Worked
2. Downgraded the version of TestNG - Not Worked
3. Installed the same version of TestNG as in pom.xml - 7.4.0 - Worked

I know it's a small mistake but wasted my 1hr.

Answer (score 0):

As Akanksha Singh mentioned, we should add the same version of TestNG dependency in a POM.xml file.
Check the version of TestNG installed:  Help > Install New Software > Already Installed e.g. 7.4.
We need to add same version of TestNG dependency, otherwise it may throw an error like below:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
> try again Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/testng/TestNGException has
> been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file
> version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class
> file versions up to 52.0

Answer (score -1):

I got this issue, after uninstalling my java jdk newer version and upgrading to java jdk older version.

I have resolved it, by recreating my java project in eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

bellow solutions fixed my issue. thanks

To overcome from this problem, we need to download the jcommander1.7 jar file. to download the jar file visit below url and get jcommander1.7 jar file

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcommander17jar.htm

Process to implement jcommander1.7 jar file-

Right click on the project->Properties->click on the liabraries->click on the Add external jars->navigate to the location where jcommander1.7 jar file is downloaded.

and run your script, now your script will run successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I was also getting this error . Please add jcommander1.7 jar as external jar .
Please follow below link
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander/1.7

Adding this external jar worked .