# Error upon executing automation code using TestNG: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: testng

My test automation project gets executed fine using the Manual TestNG execution but I am unable to execute it using the command line. I did the following:

```
1. set ProjectPath=C:\eWorkspace\myProduct\Obaid\Lexus
2. set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*
3. java -cp "C:\Software\TestNG\testng-6.9.9.jar;C:\eWorkspace\myProduct\Obaid\Lexus\bin\Tests" org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\XMLs\Lexus\Lexus.xml
3.a. Error gets thrown: Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

4. java -cp C:\eWorkspace\myProduct\Obaid\Lexus\Libs\TestNG\;C:\eWorkspace\myProduct\Obaid\Lexus\bin\Tests\ org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\XMLs\Lexus\Lexus.xml
4.1. Error gets thrown: Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
```

tried many other things to get this executed.

Referred to many other posts on StackOverflow and elsewhere: 
1. [JNI error has occurred. Please check your installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112390/jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation)
2. http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2011/10/running-selenium-testng-test-from.html
3. [Getting error Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894938/getting-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-testng-testng)
etc

Also, attached is a screenshot of my project's hierarchy.

[image: My Projects Screenshot]

Comment: From the screenshot you shared, it looks like your project is a maven project (I see `pom.xml` and `Maven dependency` folder). Why aren't you using maven to run your tests ?

Comment: To [run using maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), go to command prompt,  navigate to your project home and type `mvn test`. Refer http://testng.org/doc/maven.html for more help.

Comment: it only compiles the build but does not execute the selenium test.

Comment: It got resolved using this: https://github.com/vector-im/riot-automated-tests/issues/5